# Save component state on route change [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component (tree widget) in Angular 2.

It looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let foo in foos">
    <span (click)="isCollapsed[foo.id] = !isCollapsed[foo.id]">{{ foo.name }}</span>
    <div class="container" [ngClass]="{'hidden': isCollapsed[foo.id]}">
        <div *ngFor="let bar in foo.bars">
            <a [routerLink]=".......">{{ bar.name }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have two levels, the second level is hidden/shown when clicked on the name of an element in the first level.

The problem is that every time I click on a node in the second level, the tree loses it's state (closed nodes get open again and viceversa).

I understand that this is because of how Angular's router is re-drawing all the components, and I know that I could hack some solution using local storage to persist the state of `isCollpased`, but I'm wondering if there is a way I can make Angular remember the state of the component and apply it automatically, or even better, just reuse it somehow instead of reloading/redrawing it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

To reuse the same component, you can place it outside of the router-outlet tag in AppComponent:

```
<your-tree-structure>...</your-tree-structure>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

That could be acceptable for something like a main menu which is always present.

You can also use named router outlets - they allow you to have something like iframes so when you click a link in your tree, the tree structure will stay intact and the desired content will be displayed in another outlet.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#milestone-4
https://github.com/onehungrymind/ng2-named-router-outlets

But the custom state serialization to sessionStorage you mentioned, is a rather simple solution too. In ngOnInit() try to load the state and in ngOnDestroy() persist it. If you need it in several components, it's possible to create a generic method that would do it for any component (using something like class-transformer TypeScript library).